# How can I make more space for a bigger string in Hopper disassembler?

Tags: ios, hopper

I made an iOS app that simply changes the background color when I tap the button. the goal is to change the color with Hopper. I successfully changed the color from blue to red but I cannot change from blue to green because the string "green" is bigger than "blue" so it's overlapping the next instruction:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So my question is what can I do ?

Comment: i don't know much about hopper, but I would try something like #00FF00 instead of colorgreen if that works

Comment: @R4444 thanks, tried but not working but the questions is more "can i expand the size of a string ?"

Answer (score 1):

In practice you can't make your existing space any bigger.

Find another place in memory. You'd also need to update all the code referencing `"blueColor"` to use your new space address. One such candidate space could be strings describing segment and sections for `__TEXT` and `__text` respectively in the Mach-O header. Both of them will be exactly 16 bytes (padded with zeroes).